# How to avoid wasting Google Map usage quota due to back button?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a page that uses the Google Map API to display a series of markers together with a list of results. A detail page would be shown upon clicking of an individual result. After which a user may click the back button to go back to the results page to view another result. Each time, the Google Map would re-initialize, counting towards the usage quota. Other than making the browser open a new tab, is there a way to avoid wasting those precious quota?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I assumed that in Firefox/Chrome the map was reloaded from the back/forward cache and didn't actually count towards the api quota. Is that not the case?

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth, I tried caching the page and the script, but it didn't work. In firebug, I keep seeing the `QuotaService.RecordEvent` script being requested. I presume that this script increments the usage count. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: The only way to tell for sure would be to use an api key and monitor your usage on Google's API console.